# Using TP4056 to charge a battery with an NTC

Tags: raspberry-pi, lipo, tp4056

I'm hoping its not a duplicate question but I currently have a TP4056 and the following lipo battery: Pijuice zero 1000 mAh battery.

I'm fairly new to electronics and was wondering in this case what to do with the NTC on the battery, the TP4056 doesn't seem to have a connection for this?

So I'm wondering: is it fine to just cut the NTC short and not connect it?

The idea is to use the battery to power a rbpi zero (while not simultaneously charging).
I’m also wondering how safe it is to do this, as I've read one too many stories of lipo batteries going kaboom?

Edit: if there is a better (small) option for instead of the TP4056, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome! Please clarify _“NTC on the battery”_. Does the battery pack have a built in NTC?

Comment: Yep, black/red/yellow wire, the yellow is supposed to be an NTC connection

Battery: https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-zero-1000mah-battery

Answer (score 0):

You could just ignore the battery temperature sensor, but it is a very useful safety feature. There are other chargers ICs that can use it, e.g. BQ24081